# How can I save multiple dataframes onto one excel file (as separate sheets) without this error occurring?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
path=r"C:\Users\Wali\Example.xls"
df1=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = [0])
df2=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = [1])

with pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\Wali\Example2.xls") as writer:

    # use to_excel function and specify the sheet_name and index
    # to store the dataframe in specified sheet
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="1", index=0)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="2", index=1)
```

I'm reading the excel file which contains two sheets and then saving those sheets into a new excel file but unfortunately I'm receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?. Thanks.

Comment: either df1 or df2 isnt actually a dataframe but a dictionary. Without seeing your data or the rest of your code it is difficult to know why this is the case. Work on confirming that within the excelwriter loop that df1 is actually a dataframe  `print(type(df1))`

Comment: change [0] to 0 in `pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = [0])` will resolve this issue

Comment: Try: `df1=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=0)`, when you pass a list, a dict of dataframes is returned instead of a single dataframe.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Changing [0] to 0 did the trick. Can someone please post it as an answer so that I can mark it down as a solution. Thanks. @TalhaAnwar I'm mindful that you answered first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change [0] to 0 in pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = [0]) will resolve this issue

```
import pandas as pd
path=r"test_book.xlsx"
df1=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = 0)
df2=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = 1)

with pd.ExcelWriter(r"test_book1.xlsx") as writer:

    # use to_excel function and specify the sheet_name and index
    # to store the dataframe in specified sheet
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="1", index=0)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="2", index=1)
```